# Fixing recursive exponentiation method?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a method to do an exponentiation calculation using recursion. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static long exponentiation(long x, int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return x;
        // i know this doesn't work since im returning long
    } else if (n < 0) {
        return  (1 / exponentiation(x, -n));
    } else {
        //do if exponent is even
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return (exponentiation(x * x, n / 2));
        } else {
            // do if exponent is odd
            return x * exponentiation(x, n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have two issues. First issue is that I cannot do negative exponent's, this is not a major issue since I am not required to do negative exponents. Second issue, is certain computations give me the wrong answer. For example 2^63 gives me the correct value, but it gives me a negative number. And 2^64 and on just give me 0. Is there anyway for me to fix this? I know that I could just switch the `long`'s to `double`and my method will work perfectly. However, my professor has required us to use `long`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Long.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: @rgettman I understand this. I want to know if there is a way to get around this with what I have. I know this might sound like a stupid question, but since I am new to programming I thought I should just ask and see.

Comment: @ug_ Oh, alright. But why does it work for larger values when I change the long 's to double?

Comment: [Double.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: @rgettman Thanks for your help. You're not the person who commented this, but do you know what ug_ meant by keep their precision? Will it be "incorrect" to use double for this method? Is long the better option?

Comment: A `double` has only so much precision.  When it goes over 2^53 or so, consecutive `double` values are more than `1` apart.  So, raising any base but `2` itself (or a power of `2`) to an exponent that would reveal a value larger than 2^53 could lose precision; such a value would be rounded to the nearest `double` value.

Comment: @rgettman Thank you, this really helps!

Comment: you can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

If your professor requires you to use long, I think he/she doesn't want you to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value a long can represent is 2^63 -1. So if you calculate 2^63, it is bigger then what a long can hold and wraps around. Long is represented using [twos-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Just changing long to double doesn't exactly work. It changes the semantics of the method. Floating-point numbers have limite precision. With a 64-bit floating point number, you can still only represent the same amount of numbers as with a 64-bit integer. They are just distributed differently. a long can represent every whole number bewteen -2^63 and 2^63-1. A double can represent fractions of numbers as well, but at high numbers, it can't even represent every number.

For example, the next double you can represent after 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is 100000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000 - so you are missiong a whopping 30000000000000000000000000000000000 you can not represent with a double.

You are trying to fix something that you shouldn't bother with fixing. Using a long, there is a fixed maximum return value your method may return. Your method should clearly state what happens if it overflows, and you might want to handle such overflows (e.g. using `Math#multiplyExactly`), but if long is the return value you are supposed to return, then that is what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the result in an array of longs, let's call it `result[]`.  At first, apply the logic to `result[0]`.  But, when that value goes negative,

1) increment `result[1]` by the excess.
  2) now, your logic gets much messier and I'm typing on my phone, so this part is left as an exercise for the reader.
  3) When `result[1]` overflows, start on `result[2]...`

When you print the result, combine the results, again, logic messy.

I assume this is how BigInteger works (more or less)?  I've never looked at that code, you might want to.

But, basically, Polygnone is correct.  Without considerable workarounds, there is an upper limit.